# Out of the box approach to upload XML file to the BIRT Server for Processing

Tags: birt

I have the BIRT Report Server configured in TOMCAT and it works fine when running reports that require an XML datasource, but that XML file has be available on the network in order for the server to find it and run.  Is there an out of the box configuration in the BIRT server that will prompt the user to upload the XML file directly to the server when they try to run a given report that requires an XML data source?  This would be handy for users that have the XML datasource stored locally on their C drive and not have to move them to a network server in order to be read by BIRT.  Thanks in advance.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

There is not an OOTB solution that does what you describe.

Without the OOTB option, the best way to handle this would be using Actuate's IDAPI.  This will give you all the tools to get the file uploaded and added to the iServer.  You can expose the IDAPI interface in any number of ways including on the BIRT report itself or on a custom parameter request page.